# Update column without overwriting content in sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I need to update a column without overwriting its content. I tried with the sqlite3 syntax 'concat' which is ||, but it didn't work. This way the data is not saved and the column remains empty.

```
data = ('Hello!', 1)
sql = """UPDATE dbase SET observation = observation || ? WHERE id = ?;"""
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(sql, data)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and the column remains empty`

If the current of `observation` be `NULL`, then concatenating anything to it will also just generate `NULL`.  One option might be:

```
data = ('Hello!', 1,)
sql = "UPDATE dbase SET observation = COALESCE(observation, '') || ? WHERE id = ?;"
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(sql, data)
```

Comment: The moral of the story:  *Always* consider NULL values when working with the database--when you create a table, write a query, update the database, etc.  This is especially true when you get unexpected results and/or errors.  You might not have to change anything, but it should be considered in your mind whatever the end result.